# Injecting a field from a component into a service

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an html input and corresponding component that holds a file as a field:

html:

```
<input id="templateUpload" type="file" (change)="detectFiles($event)" class="upload-input">
```

Ccmponent:

```
export class RfqTemplateManagerComponent {

  selectedFiles: FileList;
  currentUpload: File;

  constructor(){
  }

  detectFiles(event) {
    this.selectedFiles = event.target.files;
  }

  uploadTemplate() {
    const file = this.selectedFiles.item(0);
    this.currentUpload = file;
   }
 }
```

Is there a way to take my currentUpload field and inject it into a service that's supposed to validate and manipulate the file so that I don't have to upload it again?

Comment: By `service` you mean `angular service (@Injectable())` or `server side service`?

Comment: an @Injectable() on the client

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just simply pass `File` to `service` without any further problems.

```
export class RfqTemplateManagerComponent {

  selectedFiles: FileList;
  currentUpload: File;

  constructor(
    private MyService: MyService
  ) { }

  detectFiles(event) {
    this.selectedFiles = event.target.files;
  }

  uploadTemplate() {
    const file = this.selectedFiles.item(0);
    this.currentUpload = file;
    this.MyService.currentUpload = this.currentUpload;
    this.MyService.validateFile();
   }
 }
```

Comment: You're welcome. If it's solve your problems, then please mark this answer as accepted answer (check icon).

Answer (score 0):

For your use-case, the best way would be to inject the service into your component and call the service method which validates the file. You can pass `currentUpload` as a parameter to the service method.

```
myService: MyService
constructor(myService: MyService) {
  this.myService = myService;
}


uploadTemplate() {
  const file = this.selectedFiles.item(0);
  this.currentUpload = file;
  this.myService.validate(this.currentUpload);
}
```